# How can show image in title bar?

Tags: xamarin, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I have an application in xamarin.form and I want to display image in the title bar.

I have used xamarin.form 3.6.0.2.

When i used navigationpage.titleview and run application it showing error message.
**doesn't have property titleview.**
[Build output] https://ufile.io/e1rkf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Reports_Rpt;assembly=Reports_Rpt"
            x:Class="Reports_Rpt.Signup">
 <NavigationPage.TitleView>
       <Image Source="{local:ImageResource Reports_Rpt.Images.logo.png}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="#4B8CA8"></Image>
   </NavigationPage.TitleView>


   <ContentPage.Content>

       <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Padding="2,2,2,2">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <xfx:XfxEntry 
                         x:Name="txtName"                         
                         Placeholder="Enter your name"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          />
           <xfx:XfxEntry 
                         x:Name="txtContactNum"                         
                         Placeholder="Enter your contact number"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          />
       </Grid>

   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


 [1]: https://ufile.io/e1rkf
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code and in log file. pl provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for comments...

Comment: But navigation page dose not display.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you should start your `MainPage` like this  `new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` in your `App` class.

Comment: Yes, I don't use NavigationPage, now it resolved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved by update nuget package for android.